# pandas series value lost when reindexing

Tags: pandas, indexing, series

I would like to reindex but I have a `nan` when doing it.

`pnl` np.array input:

```
2.859134e+08
```

my code:

```
pnl = pd.Series(pnl)
r = ['BCH']
pnl = pnl.reindex(r)
```

output

```
BCH   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code answers the question.

```
r = ['BCH']
pnl = pd.Series(pnl, index=r)
```